# How can I transform and count data?

Tags: r

I have a data.frame with 4 cathegorical variables with scale 1-5.

```
data.frame(
  first=c(2,3,3,2,2),
  second=c(5,5,4,5,5),
  third=c(5,5,5,4,4),
  fourth=c(2,1,1,1,2))

first second third fourth 
  2     5      5     2      
  3     5      5     1     
  3     4      5     1      
  2     5      4     1      
  2     5      4     2
```

I want to transform names of variables to one column and do cumulative counts of values and set up new variables to rows with cathegorical scale.

```
newvar  1  2  3  4  5  
first   0  3  2  0  0  
second  0  0  0  1  4  
third   0  0  0  2  3
fourth  3  2  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
dcast(melt(df), variable~value)

#  variable 1 2 3 4 5
#1    first 0 3 2 0 0
#2   second 0 0 0 1 4
#3    third 0 0 0 2 3
#4   fourth 3 2 0 0 0
```

This returns some warning since we are relying on the default options of `melt` and `dcast`, it is safe to ignore them in this case. To avoid warnings you can use this extended version.

```
library(data.table)
dcast(melt(setDT(df), measure.vars = names(df)), variable~value, fun.aggregate = length)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the cleanest method, nevertheless it works.

You use `pivot_longer` to transform the data into a long format.

Then we can group the data and count how many occurrences there are for each of your original columns.

Transform the data back into wide format using `pivot_wider` and then the last two lines rearranges the data to match your desired output.

```
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(c(first:fourth)) %>% 
  count(name, value) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "value",
              values_from = "n") %>% 
  select(name, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`) %>% 
  arrange(match(name, c("first", "second", "third", "fourth")), desc(name))
```